# Multiple emails with unique content PHP mailer?

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I want to send unique emails to multiple people (could be 1, could be 100) using PHPMailer.

$notifyemailscontent is an array that holds all the emails and names (again, could be 1 could be 100).

This below works, but I'm curious if there is a better way to do this.  It seems to take a while even when there's only like 5 emails.  Is there a quicker, more efficient way to do this type of thing? Or does it simply take this long if you're sending multiple emails?

```
/// Send notification email
    require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';
    $mail = new PHPMailer;

    $mail->setFrom('admin@mydomain.com', 'MyDomain');
    $mail->addReplyTo('admin@mydomain.com', 'MyDomain');
    $mail->isHTML(true);   // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = "FYI, there's a new entry!";

    foreach($notifyemailscontent as $email => $name) {
           $mail->addAddress($email, $name);
           $mail->Body    = "Hi $name!<br><br>
                      We're just letting you know that there is a new entry. To see it, click the link below:<br><br>
                      <a style='background: blue; color: white;' href='http://myfulldomain'>the pool name</a>

                     ";
            $mail->AltBody = "";
            $mail->send();
            $mail->ClearAddresses();  
    }
```

Comment: It depends on how you server is set up. The thing that will take time it is actual sending. You can test this by timing it (or use a profiler). On a normal server, sent mails will be queue, so it shouldn't take long at all.

Comment: You can queue mails and send them by separate process (CLI). Also try sending using SMTP.

Comment: Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps). By default PHPMailer sends using PHP's mail() function so it needs a local mail server - you can get more control (and possibly speed) by switching to SMTP.